# I need the alternative of xutils-dev library to install in CentOS

Tags: ubuntu, centos7, yum, ttcn

I am installing eclipse titan ttcn-3 on CentOS-7 and i need to install a library file equivalent to Ubuntu's xutil-dev library file. I would also like to know if any work around is there to do the same.

Edit: Following is the error i get when i try to install xutils-dev in centos -

[root@xxx yum.repos.d]# yum install xutils-dev

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
base                                                                                                                           | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                                                         | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package xutils-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
Error: No matching Packages to list

Answer (score 1):

Using the following command:

```
dnf list --avail | grep util | grep x
```

I got 269 results out of which `xorg-x11-utils` looks like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**List of available packages:** [https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xorg-x11-util-macros&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xorg-x11-util-macros&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=)

```
     # X.Org X11 Autotools macros - Dist: CentOS 7.4.1708 for x86_64
    wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/xorg-x11-util-macros-1.19.0-3.el7.noarch.rpm
    sudo yum install ./xorg-x11-util-macros-1.19.0-3.el7.noarch.rpm -y
```